# Array.max(by:) difficulty understanding

Tags: swift

I can't seem to understand the idea behind the [Array.max(by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2294243-max) operator explanation.

Consider the following line of code:

```
print([10, 2, 5, 1, 3].max { $0 > $1 })
```

I would assume that the expected output should be 10, but actually the output is 1. Now, I've read in the docs that the only argument of this function, **areInIncreasingOrder**, itself being a function, is defined as:

```
A predicate that returns true if its first argument should be ordered before its second argument; otherwise, false.
```

I just can't seem to understand this statement. Why does the adjacent element placement affect the function result?

**Note**: In the real-world example, the array would be consisted of non-primitive-type elements, where one would need to, for an example, compare dates of two objects. I understand that, if the aforementioned, simple example, was to be solved, one would simply do it with the default, [Array.max()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688806-max) operator.

Comment: don't you just want Array.max()
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688806-max

Comment: That's what I wrote up there, it doesn't work for me in my case, because I am comparing attributes of two objects, and not built-in types.

Comment: Basically by using `>` you are redefining `max` to mean `min`. Why on earth would you do that? But, whatever...

Comment: You get 1 instead of 10 because you need `$0 < $1`, not `$0 > $1`.

Comment: Instead of asking an x-y question, ask about your real situation showing your real code.

Comment: This has been discussed in the Swift forum recently: https://forums.swift.org/t/misliding-array-max-definition/26022: “*The predicate argument defines what "increasing order" is for the purposes of the function. When you use > as the predicate, you're saying that a > b implies that a is before b in the order you want to use. Since 3 > 2 and 2 > 1, 1 is the "maximum" according to the predicate that you provided.*”

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for!

Comment: OK fair enough. This was a question about the _docs_. Sorry about that.

Comment: The problem becomes clear if you replace `max` with `sorted`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quoting Steve Canon](https://forums.swift.org/t/misliding-array-max-definition/26022/3) in the Swift forum:

> The predicate argument defines what "increasing order" is for the purposes of the function. When you use > as the predicate, you're saying that a > b implies that a is before b in the order you want to use.

In your case

```
print([10, 2, 5, 1, 3].max { $0 > $1 })
```

the increasing order of the array elements is

```
10, 5, 3, 2, 1
```

and the maximal element with respect to that order is `1`.

If the intention is to get the maximal element with respect to the “natural ordering” then use simply

```
print([10, 2, 5, 1, 3].max())
```